# ExtJS 5 textfield bug (Chrome)

Tags: extjs, extjs5

I create simple application with window and 3 field:
[Fiddle Link](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/nic) (Use Chrome)

When I enter a value in the field, it looks fine.

[image: Normal]

But when I change the focus,text in field moves down.

[image]

All fields work similarly.

[image]

After click on trigger (if field has it) text looks fine.

[image]

This bug only in **Chrome**.
IE, Opera, Firefox and Vivaldi work right.
How can I fix that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a known bug for chrome. Take a look here for the workaround:

https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?301227-Visual-combobox-bug-in-Chrome-43.0.2357.65-m&p=1101244&viewfull=1#post1101244

Comment: Thanks, I missed that post(

Answer (score 1):

Css fix:

```
.x-form-text { display: inline; }
```

Demo here: http://ext4all.com/post/extjs-5-textfield-chrome-bug-fix.html